# Как получить такой формат Json

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
[{"key": "hello world", "value": "hello world"}, {"key": "movies", "value": "movies"}]
```

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду, какой должен быть исходный массив?

```
$arr = array (
  array (
    'key' => 'hello world',
    'value' => 'hello world',
  ),
  array (
    'key' => 'movies',
    'value' => 'movies',
  ),
);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: а если в цикле формировать то выходит так:

     $arr[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, уговорили. Или это у вас вопрос был? ))

Comment: Это был ответ, на то что [гуглится][1] моментально

  [1]: https://www.google.by/?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+json+php